# Which AWS service to log user application interaction events via Lambda, maybe Cloudwatch?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We are developing an API server (graphql, prisma, node) running in a Lambda (deployed via [Apex Up](https://github.com/apex/up)).

We'd like to log some user events such as:

- Login success
- Login failure
- User took action X

Currently, we just log these in our app's Aurora DB through the main API's access to the db. This results in a lot of writes and rows as users take many actions. So we're a bit uneasy about that at scale.

Just wondering if we'd be better served storing this stuff directly in Cloudwatch. Is Cloudwatch a good fit for data that we would like to be categorized and then analyzed/queried later by `user_id` and `event_type`?

Is there something else better suited on AWS or otherwise?

Comment: You can also consider [Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/elasticsearch-service)

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch is a good place to store raw, unprocessed logs.
However, you cannot query CloudWatch for custom fields (e.g `user_id` or `event_type`).

What you can do is [use CloudWatch subscription filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) to send you logs from CloudWatch to a Kinesis Stream for further processing. You could then [subscribe a Lambda Function to your Kinesis Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html).

In the Lamba function, you could whatever you want with each log entry. Here's some ideas:

- Store log entries in Parquet format in S3, to be later queried using Redshift Spectrum
- Parse log entries and send them to a Redshift database
- Parse log entries and send them to a ElasticSearch cluster, to be queried using Kibana
- etc..